# Choosing algorithm to estimate user gender by browsing history

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a task to analyze users web history to estimate age gender. As an input I have a lot of data with users browsing history. But the main complexity for me is to choose proper algorithm for this. As far as I understand the most simple approach is to rank all websites by men to woman ratio and use one of classification algorithm for this. Am I right? Could you please help me to choose proper algorithm?

Comment: Questions regarding machine learning are best suited for http://datascience.stackexchange.com/, unless you have a specific question about implementation.

Comment: @fxm should I delete this question before reposting it to [datascience.stackexchange.com](datascience.stackexchange.com)? Or there is another method to move it?

Comment: Since you already have an answer, the best would be to flag it to a moderator, and explain why in the message. I'm affraid posting the same questions on various sites is not well perceived.

Comment: How does one gain access to a person's browser history?  Is that even a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with the [Naive Bayes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) classifier, the same one that was used in the early versions of spam filters.

The idea is to give a score to each URL, which is the percentage of males for instance who have that URL in their browsing history and combine all scores of all URL in the browser history of one person to try and predict their genre.